# Errors in building Dart on CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, dart, centos6.5

Seems to be quite the adventure in attempting to build Dart on a CentOS 6.5 machine.  I'm stuck building it, since CentOS 6.5 uses glibc 2.12, and the pre-compiled build does not like not having 2.14.  Instructions for building were from here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building-Dart-on-CentOS,-Red-Hat,-Fedora-and-Amazon-Linux-AMI

On that page, "the steps described here should be sufficient for building the 64-bit Dart SDK on CentOS."  The *should* isn't so promising.  One issue with that page is that it links out to other spaces for 'do this before' type of instructions that only work with Ubuntu.  But after working thorugh some gclient sync issues and build.py 'no target for' type issues, I've hit a wall.

My question:  can someone please explain how I may resolve the following error, or at least explain what the problem I'm encountering actually is:

```
$ tools/build.py -ax64 -mrelease -v create_sdk
make -j 1 BUILDTYPE=ReleaseX64 V=1 create_sdk
  g++ '-DNDEBUG' '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' -Iruntime  -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wvla -Woverloaded-virtual -g3 -ggdb3 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fstack-protector -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -msse2 -O3 -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -MMD -MF out/ReleaseX64/.deps/out/ReleaseX64/obj.target/libdart_lib_nosnapshot/runtime/lib/regexp.o.d.raw  -c -o out/ReleaseX64/obj.target/libdart_lib_nosnapshot/runtime/lib/regexp.o runtime/lib/regexp.cc
In file included from runtime/vm/regexp.h:9,
                 from runtime/vm/regexp_ast.h:11,
                 from runtime/vm/regexp_parser.h:10,
                 from runtime/lib/regexp.cc:10:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::ReturnInstr::ReturnInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Value*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2090: error: class ‘dart::ReturnInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::ThrowInstr::ThrowInstr(dart::TokenPosition)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2120: error: class ‘dart::ThrowInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::ReThrowInstr::ReThrowInstr(dart::TokenPosition, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2146: error: class ‘dart::ReThrowInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::GotoInstr::GotoInstr(dart::JoinEntryInstr*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2199: error: class ‘dart::GotoInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::ComparisonInstr::ComparisonInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2368: error: class ‘dart::ComparisonInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::DeoptimizeInstr::DeoptimizeInstr(dart::ICData::DeoptReasonId, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2499: error: class ‘dart::DeoptimizeInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::AssertAssignableInstr::AssertAssignableInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, const dart::AbstractType&, const dart::String&, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2649: error: class ‘dart::AssertAssignableInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::AssertBooleanInstr::AssertBooleanInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Value*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2701: error: class ‘dart::AssertBooleanInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CurrentContextInstr::CurrentContextInstr()’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2732: error: class ‘dart::CurrentContextInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::ClosureCallInstr::ClosureCallInstr(dart::Value*, dart::ClosureCallNode*, dart::ZoneGrowableArray<dart::PushArgumentInstr*>*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2754: error: class ‘dart::ClosureCallInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::InstanceCallInstr::InstanceCallInstr(dart::TokenPosition, const dart::String&, dart::Token::Kind, dart::ZoneGrowableArray<dart::PushArgumentInstr*>*, const dart::Array&, intptr_t, const dart::ZoneGrowableArray<const dart::ICData*>&)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2798: error: class ‘dart::InstanceCallInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::PolymorphicInstanceCallInstr::PolymorphicInstanceCallInstr(dart::InstanceCallInstr*, const dart::ICData&, bool)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:2876: error: class ‘dart::PolymorphicInstanceCallInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::StaticCallInstr::StaticCallInstr(dart::TokenPosition, const dart::Function&, const dart::Array&, dart::ZoneGrowableArray<dart::PushArgumentInstr*>*, const dart::ZoneGrowableArray<const dart::ICData*>&)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:3221: error: class ‘dart::StaticCallInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::GuardFieldInstr::GuardFieldInstr(dart::Value*, const dart::Field&, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:3662: error: class ‘dart::GuardFieldInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::LoadIndexedInstr::LoadIndexedInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t, intptr_t, intptr_t, dart::TokenPosition)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:3815: error: class ‘dart::LoadIndexedInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::StringInterpolateInstr::StringInterpolateInstr(dart::Value*, dart::TokenPosition)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:3988: error: class ‘dart::StringInterpolateInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::StoreIndexedInstr::StoreIndexedInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::StoreBarrierType, intptr_t, intptr_t, intptr_t, dart::TokenPosition)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4026: error: class ‘dart::StoreIndexedInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::InstanceOfInstr::InstanceOfInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, const dart::AbstractType&, bool, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4113: error: class ‘dart::InstanceOfInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CreateArrayInstr::CreateArrayInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Value*, dart::Value*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4352: error: class ‘dart::CreateArrayInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::InstantiateTypeInstr::InstantiateTypeInstr(dart::TokenPosition, const dart::AbstractType&, const dart::Class&, dart::Value*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4557: error: class ‘dart::InstantiateTypeInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::InstantiateTypeArgumentsInstr::InstantiateTypeArgumentsInstr(dart::TokenPosition, const dart::TypeArguments&, const dart::Class&, dart::Value*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4594: error: class ‘dart::InstantiateTypeArgumentsInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::InitStaticFieldInstr::InitStaticFieldInstr(dart::Value*, const dart::Field&)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4658: error: class ‘dart::InitStaticFieldInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CloneContextInstr::CloneContextInstr(dart::TokenPosition, dart::Value*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4685: error: class ‘dart::CloneContextInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CheckEitherNonSmiInstr::CheckEitherNonSmiInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4710: error: class ‘dart::CheckEitherNonSmiInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::UnboxInstr::UnboxInstr(dart::Representation, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:4955: error: class ‘dart::UnboxInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::MathUnaryInstr::MathUnaryInstr(dart::MathUnaryInstr::MathUnaryKind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5103: error: class ‘dart::MathUnaryInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::MathMinMaxInstr::MathMinMaxInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5210: error: class ‘dart::MathMinMaxInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::BinaryDoubleOpInstr::BinaryDoubleOpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t, dart::TokenPosition)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5268: error: class ‘dart::BinaryDoubleOpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::BinaryFloat32x4OpInstr::BinaryFloat32x4OpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5324: error: class ‘dart::BinaryFloat32x4OpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Simd32x4ShuffleInstr::Simd32x4ShuffleInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5372: error: class ‘dart::Simd32x4ShuffleInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Simd32x4ShuffleMixInstr::Simd32x4ShuffleMixInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5439: error: class ‘dart::Simd32x4ShuffleMixInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ConstructorInstr::Float32x4ConstructorInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5501: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ConstructorInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4SplatInstr::Float32x4SplatInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5545: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4SplatInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ComparisonInstr::Float32x4ComparisonInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5607: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ComparisonInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4MinMaxInstr::Float32x4MinMaxInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5656: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4MinMaxInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ScaleInstr::Float32x4ScaleInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5705: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ScaleInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4SqrtInstr::Float32x4SqrtInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5756: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4SqrtInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ZeroArgInstr::Float32x4ZeroArgInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5803: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ZeroArgInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ClampInstr::Float32x4ClampInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5851: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ClampInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4WithInstr::Float32x4WithInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5896: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4WithInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Simd64x2ShuffleInstr::Simd64x2ShuffleInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:5949: error: class ‘dart::Simd64x2ShuffleInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ToInt32x4Instr::Float32x4ToInt32x4Instr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6007: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ToInt32x4Instr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float32x4ToFloat64x2Instr::Float32x4ToFloat64x2Instr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6045: error: class ‘dart::Float32x4ToFloat64x2Instr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float64x2ToFloat32x4Instr::Float64x2ToFloat32x4Instr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6083: error: class ‘dart::Float64x2ToFloat32x4Instr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float64x2ConstructorInstr::Float64x2ConstructorInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6121: error: class ‘dart::Float64x2ConstructorInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float64x2SplatInstr::Float64x2SplatInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6161: error: class ‘dart::Float64x2SplatInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float64x2ZeroArgInstr::Float64x2ZeroArgInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6222: error: class ‘dart::Float64x2ZeroArgInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Float64x2OneArgInstr::Float64x2OneArgInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6273: error: class ‘dart::Float64x2OneArgInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Int32x4ConstructorInstr::Int32x4ConstructorInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6331: error: class ‘dart::Int32x4ConstructorInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Int32x4BoolConstructorInstr::Int32x4BoolConstructorInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6380: error: class ‘dart::Int32x4BoolConstructorInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Int32x4GetFlagInstr::Int32x4GetFlagInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6426: error: class ‘dart::Int32x4GetFlagInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Simd32x4GetSignMaskInstr::Simd32x4GetSignMaskInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6472: error: class ‘dart::Simd32x4GetSignMaskInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Int32x4SelectInstr::Int32x4SelectInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6523: error: class ‘dart::Int32x4SelectInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Int32x4SetFlagInstr::Int32x4SetFlagInstr(dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6571: error: class ‘dart::Int32x4SetFlagInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::Int32x4ToFloat32x4Instr::Int32x4ToFloat32x4Instr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6620: error: class ‘dart::Int32x4ToFloat32x4Instr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::BinaryInt32x4OpInstr::BinaryInt32x4OpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6661: error: class ‘dart::BinaryInt32x4OpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::BinaryFloat64x2OpInstr::BinaryFloat64x2OpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6710: error: class ‘dart::BinaryFloat64x2OpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::UnaryIntegerOpInstr::UnaryIntegerOpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6758: error: class ‘dart::UnaryIntegerOpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CheckedSmiOpInstr::CheckedSmiOpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, dart::InstanceCallInstr*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6877: error: class ‘dart::CheckedSmiOpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::BinaryIntegerOpInstr::BinaryIntegerOpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:6910: error: class ‘dart::BinaryIntegerOpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::UnaryDoubleOpInstr::UnaryDoubleOpInstr(dart::Token::Kind, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7209: error: class ‘dart::UnaryDoubleOpInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CheckStackOverflowInstr::CheckStackOverflowInstr(dart::TokenPosition, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7251: error: class ‘dart::CheckStackOverflowInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::MintToDoubleInstr::MintToDoubleInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7337: error: class ‘dart::MintToDoubleInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::DoubleToIntegerInstr::DoubleToIntegerInstr(dart::Value*, dart::InstanceCallInstr*)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7372: error: class ‘dart::DoubleToIntegerInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::DoubleToSmiInstr::DoubleToSmiInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7401: error: class ‘dart::DoubleToSmiInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::DoubleToDoubleInstr::DoubleToDoubleInstr(dart::Value*, dart::MethodRecognizer::Kind, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7431: error: class ‘dart::DoubleToDoubleInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::DoubleToFloatInstr::DoubleToFloatInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7470: error: class ‘dart::DoubleToFloatInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::FloatToDoubleInstr::FloatToDoubleInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7509: error: class ‘dart::FloatToDoubleInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CheckSmiInstr::CheckSmiInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t, dart::TokenPosition)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7814: error: class ‘dart::CheckSmiInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CheckClassIdInstr::CheckClassIdInstr(dart::Value*, intptr_t, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7844: error: class ‘dart::CheckClassIdInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::CheckArrayBoundInstr::CheckArrayBoundInstr(dart::Value*, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7874: error: class ‘dart::CheckArrayBoundInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h: In constructor ‘dart::UnboxedIntConverterInstr::UnboxedIntConverterInstr(dart::Representation, dart::Representation, dart::Value*, intptr_t)’:
runtime/vm/intermediate_language.h:7925: error: class ‘dart::UnboxedIntConverterInstr’ does not have any field named ‘TemplateDefinition’
make: *** [out/ReleaseX64/obj.target/libdart_lib_nosnapshot/runtime/lib/regexp.o] Error 1
BUILD FAILED
```

So, not sure why there are a lot of issues with "does not have any field named ‘TemplateInstruction’" througout.

Whatever insight may be provided will be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know what, if any, additional information may be helpful.  Thanks for taking the time to read this over.

Comment: I don't have experience in building Dart. I suggest searching https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk issues. Posting the question in https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/misc might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more of an issue with C++ when compiling with g++, than with building Dart specifically.  Various SO questions do offer solutions as to why this error message will come up when receiving this type of error.  From what I've found, the following has a good explanation with workaround:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ67449